# Is there a good alternative hex editor instead of HxD editor?

Tags: 16.04, wine, software-recommendation

I am using now the **HxD** editor (which is a windows program, with wine).

I also have tried some GUI based (I am not interested in CLI) hex editors for linux.

Some criteria which is important for my preferences:

- When the opened file is changed, it should automatically reload.

  - In **bless** e.g. you must click the reload button.
  - In **HxD** it reload by itself (even when used as a wine program on linux).
- To change the amount of bytes in a row easily.

  - In **bless** you literally change the width of the window to change the amount of bytes per row.
  - In **wxHexEditor** e.g. you must go Options -> Preferences and then change the number
  - In **HxD** you change it directly in the tool bar
- It should be very easy to modify on the fly some bytes in hex.

  - In **wxHexEditor** to change some bytes it feels something awkeward.
  - In **bless** you do by default inserting new bytes (but I do not need insert too much, more changing bytes)
  - In **HxD** it is working (for me) very fluently.

There are some more criteria too, but these three are for me the most important ones. (also only tried out **bless** and **wxHexEditor**)

For me it does not matter what program or plugin for a program is used to fulfill my basic criteria but most important thing is: it should be (if possible) a linux program (also open source, or free to use).

Otherwise I will still use **HxD** (even if it is a windows program, I do not care, it should work and fulfill my preferences).

**Update**

For trying out, if the program is fulling correctly the reload preference, you can simply use this little python program:
[Simple numpy IO file program](https://github.com/hearues-zueke-github/python_programs/blob/master/bytes_io/numpy_bytes_io_simple.py)

Also this programs I will not use *unless* they can be changed to be optimized for my use:

*bless*, *wxHexEditor*, *GHex*, *okteta*

**Update 2**

I added one more program to the list above. Literally when I change a file and go to okteta e.g. the file is not updated by itself. Instead I need to close and reopen the same file (which makes no sense for me). Also HxD got an update, which makes the program by itself much more better. But all other criteria for *okteta* are fulfilled btw.

Answer (score 4):

You might look at `GHex`. I don't know if it'll meet your specs, but I think it's worth a look.

You can install it by running the following commands in a `terminal`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ghex
```

Or you can probably find it in the `Software` app.

Comment: Ohh, ghex is more worse than bless is. I literally updated my file, and the updated file is not showing up, even no reload button is showing up. Thanks for the suggestion. Also I do not know how to set the amount of bytes per line.

Answer (score 2):

Okteta: Hex Editor made with KDE/Qt Libraries, and as such has an amazing UI, tremendous amounts of features, and is the best I have come across thus far on Linux.

[image]

https://utils.kde.org/projects/okteta/

Comment: I have okteta right now and I must say, it is a nice program. But I do not get it, how the file can update by itself when I click into the gui...Also HxD got an update too. I do not get it, how a Windows program under Linux with WINE is better then any Linux program what I have tried so far? Thank you for the suggestion too.

Comment: @PiMathCLanguage The feature you are looking for in Okteta should be easy enough to program in... QFileSystemWatcher and a Signal/Slot connection should do it. I wouldnt mind giving it a shot... we would just need to articulate how this feature should function...

Comment: has a 2gig max limit :-(

Comment: @stu You could edit the code yourself. I made a patch for it myself and can attest that if you know Qt, then adding features is relatively simple.

Comment: well if I knew qt I've long since forgotten it by now, and my guess is that there would be performance problems which is why there's a 2gig limit in the first place, perhaps it tries to load everything into memory, or makes an index?

Comment: @stu I took a look at my IRC logs, check out freenode's #kde-devel chat, and ping a user named `frinring` << He's the maintainer and is currently doing a rewrite. I'll ask him about the progress on the rewrite, and about increasing the memory limit. For all I know, the increase in memory is simply a matter of adjusting a semaphore